# Jest Script for react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am writing a Jest Script for React Component. Please help me regarding this. How to write jest snippet for a component. Please help me regarding this. I am trying to write jest script. This is my react component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const initialShowNavBackModal = {
  showNavBackModal: false,
};

const Header = (props) => {
  const headerRef = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(()=> headerRef.current.focus(),10)
  }, []);

  const history = useHistory();

  let navBack = (currentScreenName) => {
    console.log("navBack clicked. " + currentScreenName);

    if (currentScreenName === 'LANDING_SCREEN') {
      EventMessageBridge("NAV_BACK");
    } else {
      console.log("history.goBack()");
      history.goBack();
    }
  }
  return (
    <Block>
      <div tabIndex="-1" ref={headerRef}></div>

      <Block className={styles.headercontainer}>
        {props.header}
      </Block>
    </Block>
  );
  }

export default Header;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write the Jest script snippet for React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097832/write-the-jest-script-snippet-for-react-component)

Comment: Please do not ask us to write your jest tests for you. Instead try writing your own and come back with a [mcve] if they don't work.